# If I wish to vote for a company's special meeting, should I vote via all brokers, or does voting via one broker suffice?

Tags: united-states, stocks, broker, shareholder-meeting

I own some shares in the company that will hold a "special meeting", for which shareholders have the option to cast their vote for. My shares are spread across several brokers: each of them has contacted me to give me the option to vote. If I wish to vote, should I vote via all brokers, or does voting via one broker suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broker X knows you have x shares with them, broker Y knows you have y shares with them, etc.

If you want to vote all your shares, then use the method each broker provides to vote your shares with them.